# arpreach api using add_to_list

Tags: json, api

Add to List - This function adds a contact to one or more autoresponder lists.

Function call: add_to_list

Parameters:

- email_address
- lists

JSON string with details of lists. 
Each list can contain key / value pairs of:

"list" list name

I want my email to be added to the autoresponder "Test" but i got an error:

```
{"status":"error","detail":"Contact not found"}
```

Here is the ex for the API GUIDE:

```
Example: URL http://mysite/a.php/api/add_to_list
Parameters: api_key= 0c68398f
email_address= test@example.com
lists= [{"list":"News","status":1,"next_message":2},
{"list":"Sales","format_preference":2}]
```

Here is my code:

```
http://www.domain.com/mail/a.php/api/add_to_list?api_key=1234&email_address=test@gmail.com&lists=[{"list":"Test","status":0,"next_message":0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the Contact is not found.  The *add_to_list* function is normally used to add an existing user to a new list.

Use the *add_contact* function first.  It allows you to add a contact in to the DB and assign a list to the contact record in the same call.

Once a contact record has been created you can use the *add_to_list* function to assign other lists to that contact.

arpReach differs from other autoresponders as the primary record is the email address and not the list.  An email address can exist only once and all of the other associations such as list link to it.

Also be aware that the "status":1 will set the contact as paused for any list you associate.  "status":0 is active. - see *list_responders* for other statuses.

Comment: Thanks, I already figure it out...my add_contact needs to be updated by a new version...:-)